# Eclipse. The archive which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

in eclipse I get this error when I run my program:
The archive which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
I got another program which look exactly the same but there is it working.
Here are some screenshots:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ISMI0UX.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/WZxgGXF.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/4tt6XJl.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/LQEEsHA.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/E2Dm2Qp.png]

Here are the codes from the classpath files.
Not working one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="javazoom"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Working one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="javazoom/" kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="javazoom"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
</classpath>
```

it's about the javazoom thing.
in javazoom there are only classes and no java files so I can not edit them.

Comment: Whats the error message you get? And can you append a screenshot of the unfold javazoom folder? Didn't you have a jar file?

Comment: I didn't have a jar file.
Picture of javazoom
http://i.imgur.com/vc1RJoT.png
Picture of error
http://i.imgur.com/e3DVavh.png
Picture of error from import
http://i.imgur.com/Ue5l5OC.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an idea, not sure if it works:

move the javazoom folder one folder down:
`PROJECT\libs\javazoom` instead of `PROJECT\javazoom`.

then import the `libs` folder as class folder instead of the `javazoom` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the workspace name of the eclipse and the `projectName` is not same i.e "WeLive4Money". I faced similar kind of issue and it got resolved when I changed my project name.

Comment: Thank you, but this has already been solved, like a half year ago

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this problem -

[image]

**Resolution :-**

As stated in error "The archive: /AutomationPrj/src/test/resources/**resources** which is referenced by the classpath, **does not exist**."

In my project /AutomationPrj/src/test/resources**/resources**  indeed does not exists. I created resources folder [empty] at appropriate location and issue is resolved.

[image]